# How do I connect to a specific site collection using CSOM and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I cannot find anywhere to specify what site to connect to when creating a new app for SharePoint online.

It seems to default to `https://mysite.sharepoint.com`, however, I want to retrieve lists from e.g. `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/site1`.

I tried changing the Site URL property for the project, but I get an error when Visual Studio is uninstalling the app (Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall app for SharePoint': Value cannot be null. Parameter name: AppSiteDomainPrefix).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking about, programmatically reading lists on a different site, or deploying a project to a different site. The site url property for the project would be for deployment, but you cannot deploy to just any site, it has to be a site based on the development template, or one that allows sideloading of apps, which is not on by default. So, build the app on a test site, then deploy it to the app catalog, and then you can install it on any other site you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the solution you had but for anyone else who comes here via a search engine for the error AppSiteDomainPrefix, this error seems to be quite misleading in that all the issue is is Visual Studio has had an issue installing/uninstalling the current app and you just need to manually uninstall the app from the site before hitting F5 in Visual Studio again.

I hit this error when I switched the URL to deploy to from Visual Studio (like Jocke) and got the standard [sideloading of apps error](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/12/10/enable-app-sideloading-in-your-non-developer-site-collection/). Silly me. So I ran the script to enable sideloading of apps, hit F5 again and got the error in this question (Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall app for SharePoint': Value cannot be null. Parameter name: AppSiteDomainPrefix).

It turned out although I'd had the sideloading error the app had been installed in some way, so had to be manually deleted first from site contents as per [this blog post](http://www.mavention.nl/blog/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-uninstall-app-for-sharepoint-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-value). Hitting F5 now allows the app to successfully installed to the site collection.